# Asp. Net popup window

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, popupwindow

I need to open a popup window (a new form possibly) , passing a datatable as a value, showing on a gridview, and returning the Selected Index to the parent form when I click a row. Any suggestions? Thanx...

Comment: I don't have an example but I'm pretty sure this - or variations of this - has been asked many times. You should also show your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions without code are often closed.

Comment: I've never done it but I would think that a Bootstrap popup would work, and the grid would essentially be part of the same page - it would act like a popup but you could code everything within a single page. (?) Or instead of a popup, which could be blocked, just show and hide the grid as needed.

Comment: @wazz Thanks for the tip. I did my research for Bootstrap and it worked perfectly as it should...